# Cannot update Access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to build an update button where I am able to edit the data from `Textbox`. I am using an Access database and I am having some problems and I cannot update it.

Bellow is my code:

```
private void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
        con.Open();

        string queryUpdate = @"UPDATE tblFixing SET Title=@Title, CodeBefore=@CodeBefore, CodAfter=@CodAfter, Exp=@Exp, Example=@Example, Notes=@Notes WHERE FixID=@FixID";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryUpdate);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FixID", OleDbType.WChar, 20, "FixID"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Title", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "Title"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodeBefore", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "CodeBefore"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodAfter", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "CodAfter"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Exp", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "Exp"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Example", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "Example"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Notes", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "Notes"));

        cmd.Parameters["@FixID"].Value = cmbID.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = txtTitulo.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@CodBefore"].Value = rchCodBefore.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@CodAfter"].Value = rchCodAfter.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@Exp"].Value = rchExplicacao.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@Example"].Value = rchExemplo.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters["@Notes"].Value = rchNotas.Text.Trim();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successful updated", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\nDetails: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I debug the code and it does everything but the data does not update. What should I do?

Comment: Your string is `queryUpdate`, then you use `cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryInsert);`. Is this a typo?

Comment: If `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` returns a value greater than zero, then the query worked, and you are probably looking at the wrong database.

Comment: Already edited, but that is not the problem. @Equalsk

Comment: what is the result of ExecuteNonQuery() ?

Comment: How do your check if data is updated or not? Passing 4th Argument 'srcColumn' to the constructor of OleDbParameter is not required.

Comment: Check your connection string.  If the query runs successfully with no errors, you might be running the update on the wrong table/database.

Comment: This is the right database @JackMarchetti

Comment: What did `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OleDB doesn't use named parameters.  They appear in index order.

You have the `@FixID` parameter as the *first parameter* added to the collection, but when you look at the sql string, it's the *last parameter* in the string.

Change your parameter order:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Title", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "Title"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodeBefore", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "CodeBefore"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodAfter", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "CodAfter"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Exp", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "Exp"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Example", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "Example"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Notes", OleDbType.WChar, 255, "Notes"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FixID", OleDbType.WChar, 20, "FixID"));
```